# Slow WHERE IN End of Query

Tags: sql, postgresql, where-in

Sample data from my table `test_table`:

```
date           symbol      value      created_time
2010-01-09     symbol1     101        3847474847
2010-01-10     symbol1     102        3847474847
2010-01-10     symbol1     102.5      3847475500
2010-01-10     symbol2     204        3847474847
2010-01-11     symbol1     109        3847474847
2010-01-12     symbol1     105        3847474847
2010-01-12     symbol2     206        3847474847
```

Below is the query I am currently using on a table with about 3k unique symbols and about 11 million rows. It is still taking a while (over 80% of the query time is spent on the Subquery Scan at the end (which I think is the WHERE IN clause at the end of the query. Is there any way to speed this part up (imagine I have a lot of symbols in that WHERE IN lookup).

```
select date, symbol, value, created_time
from (select *,
    rank() over (partition by date, symbol order by created_time desc) as rownum
  from test_table) x
where rownum = 1 and symbol in ('symbol1', 'symbol2', 'symbol5', ...)
```

Below is an EXPLAIN ANALYZE output if that helps.

```
QUERY PLAN
Subquery Scan on x  (cost=281573.35..282473.76 rows=129 width=37) (actual time=2874.389..3037.008 rows=32393 loops=1)
  Filter: (x.rownum = 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 183
  ->  WindowAgg  (cost=281573.35..282152.19 rows=25726 width=37) (actual time=2874.363..2980.848 rows=32576 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=281573.35..281637.67 rows=25726 width=37) (actual time=2874.340..2901.443 rows=32576 loops=1)
              Sort Key: "test_table".date, "test_table".symbol, "test_table".created_time DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3314kB
              ->  Seq Scan on "test_table"  (cost=0.00..279688.80 rows=25726 width=37) (actual time=118.338..2693.767 rows=32576 loops=1)
                    Filter: (symbol = ANY ('{symbol5,symbol8,symbol15,symbol98,symbol43,symbol908}'::text[]))
                    Rows Removed by Filter: 10649132
Planning time: 0.999 ms
Execution time: 3064.496 ms
```

Comment: Ranking isn't a cheap operation...

Comment: You could join to a table containing the symbols, but I think there is no avoiding a full table scan on `test_table`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `distinct on` instead:

```
select distinct on (symbol, date) date, symbol, value, created_time
from test_table
where symbol in ('symbol1', 'symbol2', 'symbol5', ...)
order by symbol, date, created_time desc;
```

And for this query, you want an index on `test_table(symbol, date, created_time desc)`.

Comment: Hmmm for some reason this only gives me a handful of values instead of what I am looking for... all combinations of date & symbol at the max created_time

Comment: So much faster, that really did the trick. Thank you for being patient with me and showing me the power of distinct on, certainly will read more into the details and use it in the future. Thank you again.